# Cancellation law for vector addition

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in my  linear algebra class, and I really need help understanding this proof.

The theorem states that: if x,y and z are vectors in a vector space V such that $x+z=y+z$, then $x=y$.

Proof: There exists a vector v in V such that z+v=0.
       $$x=x+0=x+(z+v)=(x+z)+v= 
   (y+z)+v=y+(z+v)=y+0=y$$

My question is: why is it allowed that they are able to move the parenthesis around? For example: $x+(z+v)= (x+z)+v$? Is it because you are able to do that because it's one of the axioms of a vector space, which is associative property?

Comment: $ $ Yes.$ \ \ $

Comment: Yes, please have a look at the definition of vector space.

Comment: Associativity is allowed in vector spaces: this comes from the field structure and the group structure.

Comment: thank you so much! I know the axioms of a vector space, but I just wasn't sure if you're allowed to use those axioms in the proof, which is kind of a stupid thought looking back. 

I have one other question. There is a corollary that the vector 0 described according to one of the Vector Space axioms, is unique.I believe that they are talking about the part where you can state that x=x+0. How would you go about proving that it's unique? Thanks :)

Comment: The proof will start with "Let $0$ and $0'$ be two vectors satisfying the additive identity axiom" and end with "$0 = 0'$".  Since $0$ and $0'$ were arbitrary, this proves there's only the one.